# Sequelize allow null set to false on foreign key

Tags: javascript, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, associations

Here is the code below for one of my tables

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const Algorithm = require('./algorithm');
const Exchange = require('./exchange');
const User = require('./user');

//@JA - This model defines the api keys for each user's exchange
//@JA - For security reasons in case the database gets hacked the keys will be stored using encryption.
module.exports = function(sequelize){
    class AlgorithmRule extends Model {}
    AlgorithmModel = Algorithm(sequelize);//@JA - Gets a initialized version of Algorithm class
    ExchangeModel = Exchange(sequelize);//@JA - Gets initialized version of the Exchange class
    UserModel = User(sequelize);//@JA - Gets a initialized version of User class

    var AlgorithmRuleFrame = AlgorithmRule.init({
        algorithm_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: { 
                model: AlgorithmModel,
                key: 'id',
            }
        },
        exchange_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            references: { 
                model: ExchangeModel,
                key: 'name',
            },
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: { 
                model: UserModel,
                key: 'id',
            },
        },
        type : { //Partial-Canceled implies that the order was partially filled and then canceled.
            type: DataTypes.ENUM('Percent Of Equity','Cash'),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 'Percent Of Equity'
        },
        type_value: { //@JA - This will be either treated as a percentage or 'cash' value for the type chosen for the algorithm.
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20,18),
            allowNull: false
        },
    }, {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'AlgorithmRule',
      indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['algorithm_id','exchange_id','user_id'] }]
    });
    return AlgorithmRuleFrame
};
```

I'm trying to set this up so that I can allownull:false on algorithm_id and exchange_id and user_id.  I want it so there HAS to be values there for any records to be allowed.

I can't even get allowNull:false manually through the database itself.  So my first question is, is this even possible?

If it is, how do I do it with sequelize?

I can use the typical hasOne() with foreign key commands because then I can't create a **composite unique of the foreign keys**.  The only way I was able to do this was the way I did using the `references:` json structure.

How do I allownull:false for a foreignKey reference defined the way I have it?

To be clear something like this will NOT work

```
Task.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false }, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
```

This will NOT work because I'm using a composite unique key across 3 foreign keys and in order to do that I need reference to it's name and that is not possible unless it's defined on the table before these commands above our input.  Hopefully this makes sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently

```
algorithm_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: { 
                model: AlgorithmModel,
                key: 'id',
            }
        },
```

This code is correct.  **HOWEVER**, **if you created the database already and the foreign key was already defined it will NOT change the allowNull via the alter command.**  You have to **COMPLETELY drop the table** and THEN it will allow the allowNull:false attribute to work.

This threw me for a loop for a long time, so I help this saves someone else a lot of frustration.